# mysqli_stmt::fetch() not fetching all data

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello guys I want to fetch all posts and comments from the database

this is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( 
        SELECT id, initiator, c_id, note, view, status, postdate, editdate
        FROM notifcations
        WHERE initiator = ? OR view = 'public'
    UNION
        SELECT id, author, pid, data, type, '' AS status, postdate, editdate 
        FROM posts
        WHERE author = ? AND type='post' OR author IN 
        (SELECT user2 FROM friends WHERE user1 = ? AND accepted = '1') AND type='post' OR author IN
        (SELECT user1 FROM friends WHERE user2 = ? AND accepted = '1') AND type='post' OR author IN 
        (SELECT followee FROM follower WHERE follower = ?) AND type='post'
) AS DATA ORDER BY editdate DESC";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username,$username,$username,$username,$username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($num_of_rows < 1){
        echo $username;
        exit();
    }else{
        $stmt->bind_result($db_id, $author, $c_id, $note, $view, $status, $postdate, $editdate);
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            if($view == 'post'){
                $stmt->close();
                $postdate = timeAgo($postdate); 
                if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")){
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $author);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->bind_result($authorravatar);
                    if($stmt->fetch()){
                        $stmt->close();
                        $authorpic = '<img src="'.$authorravatar.'" alt="'.$author.'" class="user_pic_header">';
                        $commentHTML = "";
                        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, author, data, postdate FROM posts WHERE pid = ? AND type = 'comment'")){
                            $stmt->bind_param("i", $db_id);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->store_result();
                            $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
                            if($num_of_rows < 1){
                                echo $username;
                                exit();
                            }else{
                                $stmt->bind_result($c_id, $c_author, $c_data, $c_postdate);
                                while($stmt->fetch()){
                                    $commentHTML .= $c_data;
                                }
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                }
                $postHTML .= $note;
                $postHTML .= $commentHTML;
                echo $postHTML;
            }else{
                echo 'no_post';
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    die ("Mysql Error: " . $mysqli->error);
    exit();
}
```

But its echoing only the last row from the database. What I have done wrong? I want all rows where the condition is right to output.

P.S.: I have **no** mysqlnd driver on the server so get_result() and fetch_all() won't work.

Comment: What's the query defined in `$sql`? And why do you bind `$username` so many times in the first query?

Comment: And you keep overwriting `$stmt` - and using `$stmt->close();` inside the loop? Most likely you just need one query and `JOIN`, instead of chaining queries like this.

Comment: Okay dude, i am new to this prepared stuff. How to do it then?

Comment: Add my query to the question

Comment: You can look into `JOINS` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html to reduce the amount of queries. And when you do `$stmt->close()`, that statement closes and won't be usable anymore. You open a new prepared statement using those variables, which is a good indicator that a `JOIN` may be applied - and perhaps you'll be able to reduce this to just one query instead of all the ones you have now.

Comment: is JOIN possible with my UNION query?

Comment: It's not impossible that you can replace `UNION` with `JOIN`. If you show the tablestructure, it might be easier to see what you're trying to achieve.